# npm run watch command stuck

Tags: vue.js, npm

it worked well before, but now suddenly it stuck here, for `npm run watch` command
then it stuck here

`10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…
12% building 19/27 modules 8 active ...View.vue?vue&type=template&id=301ff514&`

this is the VueJs app, It seems

`View.vue?vue&type=template&id=301ff514&`

is causing that,I have tried with update npm it doesn't solve it, any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I fixed it by running:

```
npm run development
```

Before running:

```
npm run watch
```